# Performing Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA) with Morphological Data

Tags: arrays, r, statistics, pca, morphological-analysis

I have a bunch of morphological data which I collected using the package `geomorph`. These data look like this:

259 matrices (one file per individual)  with `x` and `y` coordinates (in columns) of 20 landmarks.

```
           [,1]         [,2]
 [1,] -0.2820496783 -0.003257662
 [2,] -0.2501083238  0.020960228
 [3,] -0.2250506399  0.049100368
 [4,] -0.2015860633  0.024673340
 [5,] -0.2246826220  0.001103431
 [6,] -0.0750488845  0.133714363
 [7,]  0.0006292017  0.133626261
 [8,]  0.0679419574  0.117149206
 [9,]  0.1239612670  0.097834963
[10,]  0.2008532330  0.063564419
[11,]  0.2763894852  0.026529132
[12,]  0.3606700636  0.038228394
[13,]  0.3665535317 -0.065490660
[14,]  0.2728682794 -0.086504965
[15,]  0.1113276708 -0.147876722
[16,] -0.0742222455 -0.158015857
[17,] -0.0746248649 -0.117267412
[18,] -0.0775485339 -0.055400903
[19,] -0.1122735300  0.041616289
[20,] -0.1839993037 -0.114286212
```

The package `geomorph` contain tools to perform Principal Componant Analysis (PCA) but I don't think it contains anything for a Linear Discriminant Analysis (LDA). Or is there something?

How can I perform a LDA on this kind of data?

The solution might come from the package `geomorph` or from another package. One might as well be good enough to modify the functions from the `geomorph` package (the function `plotTangentSpace` for example. The functions of this package are usually not very long!) in order to create the function I need. Or maybe it is just a matter of transforming the data so that it is feasible with MASS:::lda (see discussion in the comments)

---

**Note:**

I have 4 semi-landmarks (sliders) within the 20 landmarks listed above! Semi-landmarks are used to evaluate not a point position but a curve. Below is my matrix containing the informations for the semi-landmarks. This matrix is called `semi$sliders` and is used as an argument of the `gpagen function as shown below:

```
> gpagen(3D_Array_With_All_Individuals, curves = semi$sliders, ShowPlot = T)

> semi$sliders

     [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    6    7    8
[2,]    7    8    9
[3,]    8    9   10
[4,]    9   10   11
```

`3D_Array_With_All_Individuals` is a 3D array where each layer is one of the 259 matrices.

Comment: Maybe you could restructure your data and then run MASS::lda()?

Comment: @Edi I don't think it is that easy. 1) First because of the semi-landmarks, then, 2) because my data contain points that makes sense in a relative way, the position of the ones relatively to the others. And finally 3) for each point, there are two coordinates (I could have 40 variables for the 20 points but still it wouldn't consider the semi-landmarks). Does it make sense? Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @Edi It might be easy as you suggest but I don't quite understand how I could restructure/transform my data for `MASS:::lda(..)`

Comment: See chapter six of [Morphometrics with R](http://www.springer.com/statistics/life+sciences,+medicine+%26+health/book/978-0-387-77789-4) by [Julien Claude](http://www.isem.univ-montp2.fr/recherche/teams/developmental-biology-and-evolution/staff/claudejulien/?lang=en) to see how to use `MASS::lda` for morphometric data. Write to Julien Claude if you're concerned about mixing semi-landmarks and see what his advice is.